# Ansible playbook cannot perform tasks on Windows host with OpenSSH

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

For some time I cannot successfully execute ansible playbook on a Windows host with OpenSSH on it.
The playbook is very simple:

```
---
- name: test play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: check if is working
      debug: msg='Start execution'
    - name: check file
      win_stat:
        path: C:\nonexistingfile
      register: out
    - debug: var=out
```

The inventory:

```
[group1]
192.168.100.6 ansible_user=Administrator ansible_password=admin1234 ansible_shell_type=cmd
```

The execution result:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -i inv/

PLAY [test play] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [check if is working] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 18 November 2021  13:04:08 +0200 (0:00:00.106)       0:00:00.106 *****
ok: [192.168.100.6] => {
    "msg": "Start execution"
}

TASK [check file] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 18 November 2021  13:04:08 +0200 (0:00:00.063)       0:00:00.169 *****
fatal: [192.168.100.6]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "An error occurred while creating the pipeline.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException\r\n ", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.100.6            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Thursday 18 November 2021  13:04:18 +0200 (0:00:10.322)       0:00:10.492 *****
===============================================================================
```

After hours of investigation I got that the problem is on the remote host side and is related to the Powershell.
Powershell version:

```
> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1237
```

On an another host with another powershell version it is working. The powershell version on that host is:

```
PS C:\Program Files\OpenSSH> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  693
```

Maybe someone also got this error and found a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["An error occurred while creating the pipeline" with latest powershell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70033459/an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-pipeline-with-latest-powershell-version)

Comment: That question is also posted by me

Comment: @Getodac you shouldn't post duplicate question, that's the reason we are looking to close it as a duplciate.